Mostrar en formato json datos en API con dos o mas líneas de registros
Por medio de postman visualizo una API que retorna datos en formato json, la API esta hecha en PHP, quisiera visualizar en postman los datos de esta forma:
{
    "status":"OK",
    "reason":"",
    "data": 
    {
        [
            { 
                "nombre": "Luis", 
                "apellido": "guerra"
            },
            { 
                "nombre": "Cesar", 
                "apellido": "Cervera"
            }
        ]
    }

Mi PHP esta así, pero solo he podido agregar una línea al array:
header ("HTTP/1.1 200");
$data = json_encode([ 
    'nombre' => 'luis',
    'apellido'  => 'guerra'
]);

$result = ['status' => 'OK', 'reason' => '','data' => json_decode($data)];
echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES );


Mete el otro array dentro de $data y listo.

Luis, el JSON que quisieras obtener no tiene un formato válido. data no puede ser un objeto e inmediatamente tener dentro un arreglo.

data está llamado a ser un array de objetos, entonces, puedes meter dentro de ese array todas las personas que necesites, algo así (evitaremos las conversiones intermedias para evitar confusiones).
$data = [ 
    [ 
        'nombre' => 'Luis',
        'apellido'  => 'Guerra'
    ],
    [ 
        'nombre' => 'César',
        'apellido'  => 'Cervera'
    ]
];

$result = ['status' => 'OK', 'reason' => '','data' => $data];

echo json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

En la salida tendrás esta estructura, totalmente válida (puedes copiar / pegar la estructura aquí para validarla):
{
   "status":"OK",
   "reason":"",
   "data":[
      {
         "nombre":"Luis",
         "apellido":"Guerra"
      },
      {
         "nombre":"César",
         "apellido":"Cervera"
      }
   ]
}

Si lo quieres convertir para trabajar en PHP puedes hacer esto:
$json = json_decode(json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
var_dump($json);

La salida es la siguiente:
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(2) "OK"
  ["reason"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["data"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["nombre"]=>
      string(4) "Luis"
      ["apellido"]=>
      string(6) "Guerra"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
      ["nombre"]=>
      string(6) "César"
      ["apellido"]=>
      string(7) "Cervera"
    }
  }
}

Y, como es natural, la lectura de la respuesta debe ser acorde a como están estructurados los datos. En data tendrás un array anidado con los datos de las diferentes personas, por lo que debes leer dentro de un bucle anidado.
echo $json->status,PHP_EOL;
foreach ($json->data as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $k=>$v) {
        echo"$k : $v",PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}

Salida:
OK
nombre : Luis
apellido : Guerra

nombre : César
apellido : Cervera

